What is the pandas version of np.select?
I feel very silly asking this.
I want to set a value in a DataFrame depending on some other columns.
I.e:
(Pdb) df = pd.DataFrame([['cow'], ['dog'], ['trout'], ['salmon']], columns=["animal"])
(Pdb) df
   animal
0     cow
1     dog
2   trout
3  salmon
(Pdb) df["animal"] = np.select(df["animal"] == "dog", "canine", "not-canine")

But the problem is that the above doesn't work!  It's because I'm providing a single value, not an array.  Arrgh, numpy.
*** ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions
(Pdb) 

I know about df.where and df.mask - but there seems to be no df.select.  What ought I do?

Related: pandas equivalent of np.where

np.select can be used here, but you need to wrap the conditions/assigned values in a list:
df = pd.DataFrame([['cow'], ['dog'], ['trout'], ['salmon']], columns=['animal'])
df['animal'] = np.select([df['animal'] == 'dog'], ['canine'], 'not-canine')

Since you have a single condition here, better use numpy.where:
df['animal'] = np.where(df['animal'] == 'dog', 'canine', 'not-canine')

Output:
       animal
0  not-canine
1      canine
2  not-canine
3  not-canine

To complement a bit @Tricky's answer, if you use case_when (a novel addition since pandas 2.2), you can have a default value by passing a catch-all condition:
df['animal'].case_when([(df['animal'].eq('dog'), 1),
                        (df['animal'].eq('trout'), 'B'),
                        (np.repeat(True, len(df)), 3),
                       ],
                      )

Also note that np.select and case_when do not handle the dtypes the same way. np.select will force a type change to have an homogeneous array, case_when will allow to create an object column keeping the original type:
df['select'] = np.select([df['animal'].eq('dog'), df['animal'].eq('trout')],
                         [1, 'B'], -1
                        )

df['case_when'] = df['animal'].case_when([(df['animal'].eq('dog'), 1),
                                          (df['animal'].eq('trout'), 'B'),
                                          (np.repeat(True, len(df)), -1),
                                         ],
                                        )

Output:
   animal select case_when
0     cow     -1        -1
1     dog      1         1
2   trout      B         B
3  salmon     -1        -1

Difference in type:
df['select'].to_list()
# ['-1', '1', 'B', '-1']    # forced type change: 1 -> '1'

df['case_when'].to_list()
# [-1, 1, 'B', -1]          # preserved type


Pandas does have an alternative to np.select, but is probably better to call it a more advanced Series.mask that accepts multiple conditions and outputs.
Is called Series.case_when and it works with tuples (condition, replacement). The problem is that it doesn't have an "else" if all the conditions fail, but there is a simple workaround where we can use the condition series == series to match everything after all the other conditions fail.
You can use different conditions as you would in np.select
Here is how it looks:
s = df["animal"]
s.case_when([(s == 'dog', 'canine'), (s == s, 'not-canine')])

End result:
0    not-canine
1        canine
2    not-canine
3    not-canine


The series itself, which U create first is the else comdition
